# How can I separate the declaration and definition of static constexpr members?

Tags: c++, c++17, header-files, constexpr

I have a set of lookup tables used in several different projects (Visual Studio), so I want to make a static library to share them with myself and others. I've been using a `Table::initialize()` function at the program entry point, but I want the initialization to be compile-time, not run-time.

```
// myLibrary.h
struct RookTable {
private:
    constexpr static std::array<U64, 64> relevancyMask = [] {
        std::array<U64, 64> mask = {};
        for (U8 index = 0; index < 64; index++) {
            U64 square = 1ULL << index;
            U64 north = (square & ~Edge::North) << 8;
            U64 east  = (square & ~Edge::East)  << 1;
            U64 west  = (square & ~Edge::West)  >> 1;
            U64 south = (square & ~Edge::South) >> 8;
            for (U8 i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                north |= (north & ~Edge::North) << 8;
                east  |= (east  & ~Edge::East)  << 1;
                west  |= (west  & ~Edge::West)  >> 1;
                south |= (south & ~Edge::South) >> 8;
            }
            mask[index] = north | east | west | south;
            if (!(square & Edge::North)) mask[index] &= ~Edge::North;
            if (!(square & Edge::East))  mask[index] &= ~Edge::East;
            if (!(square & Edge::West))  mask[index] &= ~Edge::West;
            if (!(square & Edge::South)) mask[index] &= ~Edge::South;
        }
        return mask;
    }();
    // ...
    // the members are static because the struct is not instantiable
    // ...
}
```

This works great, but **Static constexpr members must have in-class initializers,** so I use have to use a lambda function (C++17) to declare and define the array on the same line. I now also need to `include <array>` in my header file to use std::array's operator[] overload, even if I do not want `std::array` included in my application.

The solution I'm working with currently is initializing a raw array using a code generator, but it's now unclear to users what the values mean, and the source file size suffers when the array happens to be 102,400 64-bit integers. This is the only way I know to initialize my static const(expr) array members, so I'm hoping it frustrates someone enough to propose an alternative.

```
// myLibrary.cpp
const U64 RookTable::relevantMask[64] = {
    0x101010101017e,    0x202020202027c,    0x404040404047a,    0x8080808080876,
    0x1010101010106e,   0x2020202020205e,   0x4040404040403e,   0x8080808080807e,
    0x1010101017e00,    0x2020202027c00,    0x4040404047a00,    0x8080808087600,
    0x10101010106e00,   0x20202020205e00,   0x40404040403e00,   0x80808080807e00,
    0x10101017e0100,    0x20202027c0200,    0x40404047a0400,    0x8080808760800,
    0x101010106e1000,   0x202020205e2000,   0x404040403e4000,   0x808080807e8000,
    0x101017e010100,    0x202027c020200,    0x404047a040400,    0x8080876080800,
    0x1010106e101000,   0x2020205e202000,   0x4040403e404000,   0x8080807e808000,
    0x1017e01010100,    0x2027c02020200,    0x4047a04040400,    0x8087608080800,
    0x10106e10101000,   0x20205e20202000,   0x40403e40404000,   0x80807e80808000,
    0x17e0101010100,    0x27c0202020200,    0x47a0404040400,    0x8760808080800,
    0x106e1010101000,   0x205e2020202000,   0x403e4040404000,   0x807e8080808000,
    0x7e010101010100,   0x7c020202020200,   0x7a040404040400,   0x76080808080800,
    0x6e101010101000,   0x5e202020202000,   0x3e404040404000,   0x7e808080808000,
    0x7e01010101010100, 0x7c02020202020200, 0x7a04040404040400, 0x7608080808080800,
    0x6e10101010101000, 0x5e20202020202000, 0x3e40404040404000, 0x7e80808080808000
};
```

Is there any other way to initialize this out of class, or even in a separate translation unit?

I've tried numerous combinations of ultimately this same idea before switching to a lambda function:

```
struct RookTable {
private:
    constexpr std::array<U64, 64> initMask() {};
    constexpr static std::array<U64, 64> relevancyMask;
}

// ERROR: requires in-class initializer
constexpr std::array<U64, 64> relevancyMask = initMask();
```

```
struct RookTable {
private:
    constexpr std::array<U64, 64> initMask() {};
    // ERROR: function initMask() undefined / not constexpr function
    constexpr static std::array<U64, 64> relevancyMask = initMask();
}
```

```
struct RookTable {
private:
    constexpr std::array<U64, 64> initMask() {};
    constexpr static std::array<U64, 64> relevancyMask = {};
}

// ERROR: duplicate declaration
constexpr std::array<U64, 64> relevancyMask = initMask();
```

Comment: If you don't want the values in the header, you can make the tables `const` instead of `constexpr`. Then the initialization can be in a separate .cpp file. You can still use constexpr functions there to fill the tables at compile time.

Comment: A different translation unit not possible at all: `constexpr` is a compile time thing; there's no way to delay the evaluation to link time. What's the problem with `std::array` though? If you don't want to use it, it should be trivial to implement your own, (`struct Array_U64_64 { U64 m_data[64]; constexpr U64& operator[](size_t index) { return m_data[index]; } constexpr U64 const& operator[](size_t index) const { return m_data[index]; } };`),

Comment: @fabian I don't have a problem with std::array, but I would prefer to include it in an implementation file over a header file so other files don't have to include it if they don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only goal is only to make sure that the variable initialized at compile-time, then you don't need `constexpr` on it at all. You only need `constexpr` if you want to use the values in the array in compile-time contexts and in that case the initializer must be available where it it used anyway.

Whether or not a variable with static storage duration is initialized at compile-time is determined by its initialization regardless of whether `constexpr` is present. If the initialization forms a constant expression, then the compiler must perform constant initialization to initialize the variable. This means in practice that it must perform the initialization at compile-time without any runtime call.

So, if you simply make the array `const` instead of `constexpr` and then use the same lambda initializer in an out-of-class definition, then it will be initialized at compile-time.

Unfortunately it is a bit hard to recognize whether or not the initialization is a constant expression. For example if you move the lambda into a function which you call in the initializer of the variable instead, then whether or not the initialization is a constant expression will depend on whether the function is marked `constexpr`.

C++20 introduced `constinit` to make this less error-prone, which when added to the out-of-line definition would cause a compilation error in case the initialization is not actually a constant expression.